# Writing a javascript conditional - active/inactive button

Tags: javascript, xcode, conditional-statements, cordova

I have this script, which works great at the moment to navigate

```
window.uicontrols.createTabBarItem("home", "Tab 1", "icon1.png", {
  onSelect: function() {
    jQT.goTo("#home", "slide");
  }
});
```

window.uicontrols.createTabBarItem("tab2", "Tab 2", "icon2.png", {
  onSelect: function() {
    jQT.goTo("#tab2", "slide");
  }
});

The only problem is that when a user clicks the button twice (ie. clicks it when they're already on the active content) it screws things up.

I'm quite new to javascript, and was wondering if someone would please be able to explain how I might go about writing an appropriate conditional:

**1.** to stop the tab button being selectable after it has been clicked

**2.** and then become selectable once more when a different tab is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My javascript is rusty, so forgive the syntax errors:

```
// A global variable to hold the currently active tab
var activeTab;

window.uicontrols.createTabBarItem("tab2", "Tab 2", "icon2.png", {
  onSelect: function() {
    myName = "#tab2"
    if (activeTab != myName)
    {
        jQT.goTo(myName, "slide");
        activeTab = myName;
    }
  }
});
```

Or if you can modify the function "jQT.goTo", you could put this logic there to prevent going to a place multiple times

To prevent the tab from being clicked, you could set the "disabled" attribute on it, or come up with some other visual cue that clicking on it won't do anything

Comment: Thank you!  The only part i had trouble with was the jQT.goTo(activeTab, "slide"); line.  Which only worked when i specified it directly.  eg. jQT.goTo("#tab2", "slide");

Comment: whoops, that should have been "myName" instead of "activeTab".  I fixed the answer.  BTW, its good programming practice to use variables or constants instead of "magic" literals like "#tab2".  Especially if you use it more than once; this protects you from typos etc.  See also the "DRY principle"